# Bypass/deactivate validation rules, workflow rules, process builders in apex class

Tags: batch, process-builder, validation-rule, schedulebatch, workflowrule

We are writing batch job to update a field one of object records through batch(around 500K records). I have validation rules, workflow rules, process builders on this object which increases the batch processing time. We need to bypass all of these in batch job to reduce processing time. What is the best way to do this?

Can we deactivate the metadata related to the object in start of the batch and reactivate in the finish method?

Answer (score 2):

Metadata API access via Apex `https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi`
works in Async mode.

Even if you do this is `start` method of your batch, there is no guarantee that it will disable all those by the time your `execute` method starts.

As a long term and stable, its better to go for a hierarchy `CustomSetting` approach, change all you automations to have a check before triggering. Insert this from start method and in finish just delete this custom setting from Apex.